# Android Studio two buttons Java code error

Tags: java, android

```
Can anyone tell me what I am missing, this is driving me crazy.
```

Below is the java code for the Profile Activity. I've only been at this for about 30 days now and a lot is still confusing to me.

When I run the emulator, it opens, then crashes after the first button
that is supposed to send the user to the second activity.

Running Logcat, it gets hung up on line 26 of the page posted below, stating it hates something about my Listener for Button 2.
Help???

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        // Button Click Goes to Main Activity
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_over);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                back();
            }
        });
        // Button Click Goes To Third Activity
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forward);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                forward();
            }
        });
    }

    private void back() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void forward() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Logcat File is below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.defy, PID: 2481
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.defy/com.defy.ProfileActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at com.defy.ProfileActivity.onCreate(ProfileActivity.java:26)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

MainActivity .XML Below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.defy.trailmaster.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_hiking"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/app_start"
        android:textColor="#FDFEFE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.868"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.966"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="242dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tent"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hiker_right"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.991"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.889"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/hiker_right"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main Activity .JAVA Below:

```
    package com.defy.trailmaster;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Button Click Goes To Profile Activity
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_hiking);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                hike();
            }
        });
    }

    private void hike() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Last is the Manifest file Below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ProfileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ThirdActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Profile Activity XML Below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.defy.trailmaster.ProfileActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start_over"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/app_back"
        android:textColor="#FDFEFE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.145"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.966" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hike_now"
        android:layout_width="95dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:text="@string/app_hike"
        android:textColor="#FDFEFE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.868"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.966" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tent"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.26"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/tent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_hiker"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="42dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="42dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/start_over"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/hiker_right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/hiker_left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/hiker_right"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.991"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.889"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/hiker_right"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints,RtlHardcoded" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your activity's layout xml to your question.

Comment: Please post your XML as well.

Comment: post your manifist

Comment: post your logcat output. where is the line number 26?

Comment: Logcat was added

Comment: Added XML and the Java file for the Main Activity

Comment: Manifest up now too

Comment: Obviously `activity_profile` does not contain the forward ID

Answer (score 1):

It is crashing most likely due to `R.id.forward`, `button2` is `null`.
It looks like you either named the button id something else, or missed it.

Post the XML for ProfileActivity

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem. button2 should refer to hike_now

```
 Final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hike_now);
```

Comment: @Stack_Master no problem! I recently started developing for android, it, too, got me frustrated at first.